# Android Get File that Opened Activity with Intent Filter

Tags: android, file, android-intent, filter

I added an intent filter to my activity for a specific type of mime and extension, so when I click on that file it opens the activity that is supposed to open.

Thats awesome, and its working!

But how can I get the file that I clicked? 
I guess that its possible.

Can someone give me some hints?
Thanks alot in advance ;)

**EDIT:**

I Have this on my AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.activities.omega1.SlaveLoadConfig"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_slave_load_config"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.sso" />
                <data android:host="*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And I already have files with extension .sso opening the SlaveLoadConfig activity, but I would like to have an handler to get the content of the file, how ?

Comment: Can you past some of your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution :P

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.getData().toString();
```