# Registering and using custom extension via AndroidManifest.xml using Icenium / Kendo / Cordova

Tags: android, parameters, cordova, arguments, file-type

I've successfully associated my custom file extension with my app via the AndroidManifest.xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="$AndroidVersionCode$"    
                android:versionName="$BundleVersion$" 
                package="$AppIdentifier$" 
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
                android:hardwareAccelerated="$AndroidHardwareAcceleration$"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <supports-screens
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true"
            android:resizeable="true"
            android:anyDensity="true"
            />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" 
                             android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
                             android:hardwareAccelerated="$AndroidHardwareAcceleration$">
            <activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
                android:name=".TelerikCallbackActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
                android:launchMode="standard"
                                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
                    <intent-filter >
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                  <intent-filter
                    android:label="Sonic Images"
                    android:priority='1'>
                    <category
                      android:name='android.intent.category.DEFAULT'
                    ></category>
                    <action
                      android:name='android.intent.action.VIEW'
                    ></action>
                    <data
                      android:host='*'
                      android:pathPattern='.*\\.simg'
                      android:scheme='file'
                    ></data>
                  </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
</manifest>
```

However, I still have two issues/questions:

(1) When I click on a file of type .simg, my app loads.  But all .simg files still show with the question mark (?) icon.  My application's icon shows up correctly on my home screen for the app itself, and when it shows up in select lists the icon shows up correctly, but not for individual .simg files in the file explorer. How can I get the icon to show properly in file explorers?

(2) When I click on an .simg file, my app loads, but how do I capture the name of the file that was clicked on, keeping in mind that I'm not developing in Java, but using the Kendo UI / Cordova framework.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Hi, Did you manage to resolve this issue?I am facing the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

1) To change the file icon, try putting an icon attribute on your `intent-filter` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18578704/16387) -

```
<intent-filter android:icon="your_drawable-resource"
               android:label="your_string_resource"
               android:priority="integer"> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.YOUR_CUSTOM_FILE_EXTENSION" />
</intent-filter>
```

2) To capture the opened file path, see the example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755861/android-get-file-that-opened-activity-with-intent-filter) -

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.getData().toString();
```

Of course that's Java code, so you'll have to translate that to [WebIntent](http://smus.com/android-phonegap-plugins/) for Cordova. Maybe [this article](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/05/01/Example-of-Intents-with-PhoneGap) will help readers. It shows the following script. It's possible the `url` variable here would be the path to your file:

```
<script src="cordova-1.6.1.js"></script>
<script src="webintent.js"></script>
<script>
function init() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",deviceReady,false);
}
function deviceReady() {
    console.log("Device Ready");
    window.plugins.webintent.getUri(function(url) {
        if(url !== "") {
            // url is the url the intent was launched with
            document.querySelector("#test").innerHTML = "URL was "+url;
        }
    });

}
</script>
```