# How can I open my Android app through share screen?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I want my app to be shown on the share screen dialogue of android.
Like when we using our file manager and want to open any file (let's say) with mp4 extension. Then we'll get the list of all the mp4 media player of our phone. Or if you choose to share any file then we'll get the list of all the apps that can share the file like WhatsApp, xender, etc.
Similarly, I wanted to open .txt file In my app Text To UI (app name).
Though I already know how to open the file manually.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRjSXZPYiVY

Comment: You have to use Deep linking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Get File that Opened Activity with Intent Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755861/android-get-file-that-opened-activity-with-intent-filter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code in Manifest under that activity which is open on share

If `MainActivity` is not launcher activity, Add below code in Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If `MainActivity` is your launcher activity and as well as that activity which is open on share, Add below code in Manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
             <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

MimeType `"text/*"` is for send only text type data.

MimeType `"image/*"` is for send only images type data.

MimeType `"video/*"` is for send only video type data.

MimeType `"*/*"` is for capable to send all type of data like video,audio,image,text

For getting data in your App try below code in activity:

```
 Intent receiverdIntent = getIntent();
        String receivedAction = receiverdIntent.getAction();
        String receivedType = receiverdIntent.getType();

        if (receivedAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)) {


            Uri receiveUri = (Uri) receiverdIntent
                    .getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

            if (receiveUri != null) {
                Log.e("Shared",receiveUri.toString());
            }else{
                Log.e("Shared","Nothing");
            }

        }
```

App is in sharing list:

[image]

I hope it works for you.

Comment: @Vijay, Please check Edited answer